# How to convert stream into Excel sheet (.xls and .xlsx) without any third party tool

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
Stream inputstream = Exceluploader.PostedFile.InputStream;

if (extenstion == ".xls")
{
   //1. Reading from a binary Excel file ('97-2003 format; *.xls)
   excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(inputstream);
   excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
}

if (extenstion == ".xlsx")
{
   //...
   //2. Reading from a OpenXml Excel file (2007 format; *.xlsx)
   excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(inputstream);
   excelReader.IsFirstRowAsColumnNames = true;
}
```

Currently I am using ExcelDataReader open source to convert the stream into Excel sheet and then into dataset, same I want to perform without any external party tool or dll

Comment: If you don't want to use any third-party tool - you'll have to write **a lot of code** yourself (that's already been written many time over by those who publish those third-party tools) ......

Comment: @marc_s Any ideas of which third party tools can do this? thanks

Comment: @Standage: any of the big .NET tool vendors have offerings - we use Aspose.Cells by Aspose Pty., but DevExpress, Telerik, SyncFusion - they all offer some form of functionality to read and write the basic Office formats very easily

Comment: @marc_s do you have a code sample for aspose.cells to convert stream in xls to stream in xlsx? I tried googling it and wanted to try the free trial

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Third party tools exist for a reason. It is to make your life easier. If you want to be able to read all of this by yourself without a third party tool, you will need to begin to research the specifications of the XLS and XLSX formats and interpret them yourself.

Checkout these links for [XLS](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC0QFjAA&url=http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/B/E/0BE8BDD7-E5E8-422A-ABFD-4342ED7AD886/Excel97-2007BinaryFileFormat%28xls%29Specification.pdf&ei=VjvTUameB4KCyAHNyIHQAw&usg=AFQjCNETpkoL92bZEmPpzCro1O5V6Lex3w&sig2=ftWVBUihvgAk9lIr_XcrlA&bvm=bv.48705608,d.aWc) and [XLSX](http://download.microsoft.com/download/D/3/3/D334A189-E51B-47FF-B0E8-C0479AFB0E3C/%5bMS-XLSX%5d.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Dan for the pdf, i will try to generate our own dll.